# Why does matlab not link my C MEX code?

Tags: visual-c++, matlab, compilation, mex

I have the following problem in compiling my mex C functions using MS VC++ Compiler: I have a function `disc_rhs__` in a separate file `disc_rhs.c` which was createtd by f2c (which should be unimportant, but...). In my main function I write somewhere

```
...
disc_rhs__(...);
...
```

I try to compile using

```
mex sfun_kalman.cpp -L. -llapack -lcblas_WIN -lblas_WIN -lf2c disc_rhs.c kalmanfilter_f2c.cpp
```

This leads to an error. The linker cannot find the external symbol `""int __cdecl disc_rhs__(double *,double *,double *,double *,double *)" (?disc_rhs__@@YAHPAN0000@Z)"` used in the `kalmanfilter.cpp`.

To get everything compiling I copied the `disc_rhs.cpp`to `disc_rhs.h` and removed the function declaration just letting a stub. This I included in `kalmanfilter.h`.

So why does matlab mex compiler not recognize the corrct symbol and link with the compilation of `disc_rhs.c`?

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put the entire contents of `disc_rhs.cpp` into a header file and then include it in another file. This will only work as long that file is being included by a single source file, as soon as you include it in another source file you'll get multiple definition errors.

The right way to fix this problem is to create a `disc_rhs.h` file that contains the prototypes of all functions from `disc_rhs.cpp` that need to be used by other modules. Then you'd include the header file in `kalmanfilter.cpp` (and any other files that need to use those functions).

**EDIT:**
The error is happening because the `disc_rhs` file has a *.c* extension which causes MSVC to compile it as a C file. However, since it is being used in `kalmanfilter.cpp` the linker is expecting to find a C++ function that has been name mangled, which doesn't exist. To fix the problem, you need to tell the compiler that `disc_rhs__()` is a C function.

In disc_rhs.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
int disc_rhs__(double *,double *,double *,double *,double *);
```

The `extern "C"` directive needs to appear in front of each item being exported by `disc_rhs.c`, so if you have several things to extern, the following syntax is more convenient.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int disc_rhs__(double *,double *,double *,double *,double *);

// other stuff being externed

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry for expressing me badly. I deleted everything except for the lines that define my function. You call it prototype. That might be the official name. It's like
`int disc_rhs__(doublereal *x, doublereal *u, doublereal *t, doublereal *params, doublereal *val);`

Comment: @ChristianWolf That should be good enough. Is `kalmanfilter.cpp` including `kalmanfilter.h`? Also, try moving the names of all the source files to the beginning of the mex command. `mex sfun_kalman.cpp disc_rhs.c kalmanfilter_f2c.cpp ...`

Comment: Yes `kalmanfilter.cpp` includes `kalmanfilter.h`. Change of order in the mex command does noch change anything about the error.

Comment: @ChristianWolf Is `doublereal` the same as `double`? Your prototype shows the data type as `doublereal` but the linker error shows it's trying to find a function that takes `double`. Maybe you need to type cast the arguments to `disc_rhs__` when you call it.

Comment: `typedef double doublereal;` is in `f2c.h`. A manual cast to (doublereal*) does not even change the text of the error message (again looking for `disc_rhs__(double*...)`.

Comment: I hav found out the following: If I compile as C++ code (rename to .cpp instead of .c) the linker does find the symbols correctly. Unfortunately now the sin and cos functions are missing. If I add cmath in the header includes, I get several sytax errors in the cmath and math.h file (MS VC 9.0). Any ideas?